# How can I add multiple ssl certificates to curl.cainfo in php.ini?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, php-ini

I'm running Apache locally for developing multiple sites and would like to run them simultaneously. The sites talk to each other over ssl, and since it is a local setup, I'm using self-signed certificates.

To get php(5.5.26) to accept these certificates, I added them to the `curl.cainfo` property in `php.ini`. I got it to work with one certificate, but when I try adding multiple (3), it doesn't work (I don't get anything back when making a request from one site to the other in php). I tried the following formats:

Separate Lines:

```
curl.cainfo=/path/to/certificate.crt
curl.cainfo=/path/to/another/certificate.crt
curl.cainfo=/path/to/last/certificate.crt
```

Same line, comma separated
    `curl.cainfo=/path/to/certificate.crt,/path/to/another/certificate.crt,/path/to/last/certificate.crt`

Same line, colon separated
    `curl.cainfo=/path/to/certificate.crt:/path/to/another/certificate.crt:/path/to/last/certificate.crt`

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying [CURLOPT_CAINFO](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html) option in libcurl only supports a single file name, and PHP/CURL merely passes on that string to libcurl. So no, you cannot pass more than one file name. You can however concatenate all those files into a single one, and point to that.